# Finding what Tris in a model that will contain non-opaque texels

Tags: c++, opengl, blender

I have a character model I made in Blender that I'm rendering with OpenGL.  The model's texture uses the alpha channel heavily, and I need to treat triangles that are translucent special (depth sorting them in this case).

This means I need to discover which tris these will be.  The way I am doing it now is by very VERY slowly going over every triangle in the model, using the UV coordinates of the three vertices, and checking first if pixels in the texture fall in the triangle, then checking if any of them are not opaque.

For a single model of 2500 tris, and a texture size 4096x4096, this process takes about one minute.  Too long to do in real time or even loading I think, since there's many models that need loading.

Is there a faster technique of determining where the transparent tris are, fast enough to use in real time?  Or would one just need to precompile the results beforehand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like something that should be avoided all together at run-time by decomposing the meshes beforehand. Separate all triangles that contain UV coordinates which encompass a translucent pixel into its own mesh. Then at run-time only depth sort the triangles of the 'translucent' meshes. The separation process can be done while you're compiling the model from it's interchange format to its run-time format.

You could hypothetically put a buffer on the GPU with an bool for every triangle, initialized to false. Then write a fragment shader that checks the current fragments alpha, and if it is < 1, set the bool for the respective triangle to true. This would require drawing the scene, reading the buffer back from the GPU, sorting the flagged triangles, then redrawing the scene. This should be feasible for real-time performance but seems wasteful considering the entire process can be avoided by doing everything beforehand.

Comment: How about examining all possible alpha values in textures, vertex colors, materials and then making a decision based on that? Don't forget the GPU might cull/clip/scissor a portion of your rendered triangles - even a single pixel - making the result of analysis invalid.